# Problem with pagination from database question

Tags: mysql, pagination

I use a pagination for a soccer prediction page. Each user can have more than one prediction.
In userdata table the users info is stored with uniqe ID. Then I have another table called matchtips where the predictions is stored and user ID is connected to it. In that table I also have a row called tips_number. If you have three predictions you have tips_number 1 , 2 and 3 for example.
To get the data from the database I use this question.

```
SELECT A.name, lastname, B . *
FROM userdata A
LEFT OUTER JOIN matchtips B ON ( A.id = B.user_id )
WHERE A.id IN (14,15,16,24,25,36,48,49,52,52)
AND B.league_id = '2020'
AND paid = '1'
GROUP BY A.id,tips_number,match_id
ORDER BY match_id, lastname, name, tips_number ASC
```

No problems so far. But when a user with more than one tips_number and coming to pagination break points things happen. Pagination is supposed to show 10 users at a time. ID 52 has three predictions (tips_numbers) and two should be shown on one page and the third as start of ten new IDs in the next page. But what happens is that both pages show all three predictions on each page. Three in the end of the first page and same three as start in the next one. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After alot of struggling i finally got it right. I had to use sub querys to get it right.
The `$start` and `$cols_per_page` is from the pagination class and where earlier used to get the ids in the `WHERE IN` in the old question.
So this is how the question looks now. It works like a charm and also use key pagination instead of pagination with `LIMIT and OFFSET`.

```
SELECT * FROM 
      (SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY surname, name, tips_number) offset_ FROM
        (SELECT A.id, name, surname, B.* 
         FROM userdata A, matchtips B 
         WHERE A.id = B.user_id
         AND B.league_id = '$lid'
         AND paid = '1'
        GROUP BY A.id, tips_number, match_id) result) result_offset
    WHERE offset_ > '$start' AND offset_ <= ('$start' + '$cols_per_page')
    ORDER BY result_offset. match_id, surname, name, tips_number ASC
```

This article put me in the right direction. [Paging One-to-Many Results in SQL](https://oncodesign.io/2017/04/22/paging-one-to-many-results-in-sql/)